# Disable email notification for commits done in cvs

Tags: cvs

How do I disable commit notifications for a particular user in cvs?

Comment: You can probably use cvs watch to do this see  http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/using-cvs-watches.html

Comment: cvs doesn't do commit notifications by default. Someone has set it up for your system so you'll have to work out what they set up (eg. CVSspam: http://www.badgers-in-foil.co.uk/projects/cvsspam/). Once you know that, you'll be in a better position to find out how to disable certain users.

Comment: I was able to do that, Thanks for the help